# Both CTRL key not working on laptop

Tags: keyboard

Both ctrl keys are not working. For the last 2 weeks it had times when it worked, but most of the time they didn't. I tried to reinstall drivers, OS, update BIOS. Nothing worked. Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the keyboard is just bad? Have you plugged in an external keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning it?

Comment: Desktop, laptop, or other?

Comment: Its odd that its *both* control keys dont work and you all the other keys work.  that would immediately point to software issue in my mind, but you said you reinstalled the OS.  Just to be sure, attach another keyboard via USB.  If the ctrl keys on the external keyboard do work, then it is most likely a hardware issue.